# inequality symbolic toolbox

Tags: matlab, function, inequality

```
 100<=P1<=200 100<=P2<=200 100<=P3<=200 80<=P4<=200 P3+P4<=210
 F=45*P1+50*P2+60*P3+48*P4 =>min
```

I cant find way how to implement this `F` going to the minimum value of all
 answers

```
       syms P1 P2 P3 P4 PL5
       Z=solve('P1>=100','P1<=200','P2>=100','P2<=200'
       ,'P3>=100','P3<=200','P4>=80','P4<=200','P1+P2+P3+P4=500','P3+P4<=210')
```

Comment: Why symbolic math? Try `fmincon`

Comment: Do you require the `P` values you're solving for to be be integers by chance?

Comment: Given your first set of equations, the solution is `P1=100`, `P2=100`, `P3=100` and `P4=80`. If you include the constraint that their sum must be 500, then `P1=200` and `P4=100` and `P2` and `P3` don't change. No coding needed!

Comment: I know that it is possible to do with hands, but how to implement this in matlab to solve?